# ORA-03113 when using dbms_xmlschema.registerschema

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

I am trying to register a Xml schema to validate some xml documents, using Oracle plsql stored procedures. Here is the piece of code :

```
begin
    dbms_xmlschema.registerschema(
         schemaurl => 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd',
         SCHEMADOC => bfilename('XMLDIR','xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'),
         local => false,
         gentypes => false,
         gentables => false,
    );
end;
```

My XML schema is not local, so I have to set **local** to **false**. I precise that all these statments are executed under SYS user.

I have already created a directory and granted access to everyone with following commands :

```
create or replace directory XMLDIR as '/absolute/path/to/xmlschema';
create public synonym XMLDIR for XMLDIR;
GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY XMLDIR TO PUBLIC;
```

I have noticed that if the file **xmldsig-core-schema.xsd** is not present on disk before I run the first plsql block, the result is **ORA-22288** error (file or LOB operation string failed string). So I created the **xmldsig-core-schema.xsd** file before.

When I run *dbms_xmlschema.registerschema...* I get the error **ORA-03113 : end-of-file on communication channel**

WHat's wrong ? Any Ideas ?

Comment: Is there a firewall that is restricting access to `http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`?

Comment: No problem with any firewall. when I run the command "wget http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" on the oracle db server, I obtain the file.

Answer (score 0):

The DTD is probably not accessible due to proxy or firewall issues. You can remove or comment the DTD reference from the XML schema and try registering it.

If you want to be able to register the schema without editing it you would need to ensure that you can use the `httpuritype()` to access the URL for the DTD without any errors before attempting to register the schema.

```
select httpuritype('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd').getClob() from dual;
```

Comment: Annjawn, when I execute "select httpuritype('http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd').getClob() from dual;", the statement is successfully executed. But I still have the problem of ORA-3113.

Answer (score 0):

**ORA-03113** means that your connection is died. For some reason, your client machine and the database server stopped talking to each other.
Possibility :

- server is down?
- problem with your network cable ?
- process was killed?
- log full?
- Oracle internal error?

Look in your alert log. More information here : [How to solve Error Message ORA-03113 in Oracle 11g ?](http://www.oracle-error.com/11g/ORA-03113.html)